# pyautogui works from terminal but not tkinter button

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, pyautogui

Good evening,
I'm trying to learn some Python coding so I've written a short script that searches the screen for a button and then clicks the button a specified number of times.  I have the code under 'RunScript' also saved as it's own file.  When I run that script from terminal it works fine, but when I try to execute it by double clicking the icon, or from a button on a tkinter box using the below code it asks me for a number of loops and then does nothing.  I'm working in a Lubuntu virtual machine.
Please can you tell me what I'm missing?
Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import easygui
PauseStatus = False

def RunScript():
    LoopCount = easygui.enterbox('How Many Loops?')
    for i in range (int(LoopCount)):
        if PauseStatus:
            easygui.msgbox(str(i) + ' loops completed\n' + str(int(LoopCount)-i) + 'loops remaining')
            PauseStatus = False
        while True:
            ButtonPos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('MyButton.png')
            if ButtonPos is not None:
                break
        pyautogui.click(ButtonPos[0],ButtonPos[1],duration=0.25)
    while True:
        ButtonPos = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('MyButton.png')
        if ButtonPos is not None:
            break
    easygui.msgbox(str(i+1) + ' loops completed')

root = Tk()
ControlPanel = Frame(root)
ControlPanel.pack()

startbutton = Button(ControlPanel, text="Start",command = RunScript)
startbutton.pack(side = LEFT)

stopbutton=Button(ControlPanel,text="Stop")
stopbutton.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: run tkinter script in terminal - maybe you get error mesage.

Comment: btw: `locateOnScreen` returns always the same position (of first found button) so you don't need use `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you.  I ran from terminal and got the error message you mentioned below.  I moved the PauseStatus to inside the def part and now it works.

Comment: The button greys out after it has been pressed and then un greys when it is ready to be pressed again.  The purpose of the while loop is to make sure the code doesn't try to press a greyed out button, although I do intend to change this to store the button location as a seperate and then only search that area of the screen for the image each loop to make it quicker.  I also have read that to make Pause work I will need to change the while loop to an after, but I'm still trying to make that work.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have error message similar to this

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1539, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 11, in RunScript
    if PauseStatus:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'PauseStatus' referenced before assignment
```

You have to use `global` in function `RunScript`

```
def RunScript():
    global PauseStatus
```

or you have to declare variable inside function as local variable

```
def RunScript():
    PauseStatus = False
```

Comment: I got this error message in terminal and applied your fix.  Now the code works when I click the button on my tkinter box.
Thanks